# How to allow user to use one exposed filter and select between two views

Tags: 7, views, search

I am using the [search_api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module with views as the back-end. Users will have the ability to search through two different kinds of content, and there will be two separate views (one for each content type) to power the search results. I want to expose **one** search box, but then allow the user to direct those search terms to one view or the other.

Here is a picture that should make my desire more clear:

[image: Search Bar]

If the user selects "songbook", then their search gets directed to the song view. If they select "blog", then their search is directed to the blog view. How do I accomplish this using views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually views with exposed filters use get params fx

```
example.com/view1?filter_a=search
example.com/view2?filter_b=search
```

If you create your own form then build the URL bases on input and search type it should work just fine. I don't think it will be possible to do a view selection with exposed filters.