# How do exposed views filters make their queries URL safe?

Tags: 7, views

I'm [creating my own search form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37041/how-to-allow-user-to-use-one-exposed-filter-and-select-between-two-views) in D7, and I need to sanitize the search text so that it is URL safe. I need to mimic the way that the views module does it because I'm using the search_api module and views.

In short, I need to make this:

"what is going on around here, anyway?"

look like this:

what+is+going+on+around+here%2C+anyway%3F

How do I do that?

Comment: urlencode() can do that I believe. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php I'm not sure how Views does it though.

Comment: I have been looking all through the views codebase to try and figure out how they're doing it. They aren't using urlencode, though, I know that. Just ran a search to check it out and I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7)() function to encode your URLs.

```
url("what is going on around here, anyway?");
```

this will return the string `'/what%20is%20going%20on%20around%20here%2C%20anyway%3F'`

You could also use this to get the full, absolute URL.

```
url("what is going on around here, anyway?", array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

You may also be interested in the [l](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)() function if you need html output.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is what I did:

```
function my_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  if ($form_state['values']['area'] == 'cookbook') {
    $search_string = 'http://example.com/cookbook?recipe-search=';
  }
  elseif ($form_state['values']['area'] == 'blog') {
    $search_string = 'http://example.com/blog?blog-search=';
  }

  $search_string = url($search_string . urlencode($form_state['values']['search_value']));

  $form_state['redirect'] = $search_string;
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of $search_string in the first part of the url function and where does it come from?  `url($search_string`...

Comment: Good question. Here it is: `$search_string = 'http://mysite.com/blog?blog-search=';`. Notice that I used the absolute URL. I had to do that to keep it from encoding the first part of the search string.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include the entire function.